# Regular expression and search text to text; solr

Tags: java, regex, search, solr

there 
Is possible get by regular expression something like:

011* TO *22

where all searching word start from '011' and end at '22'
example:

```
 011-02
 011K02
 011pr12
 011112
 011222
 011322
```

?

Comment: Are you asking how to extract the text between "011" and "22" using Regex?

Comment: What is the definition of a 'word'? A series of non-space characters? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I just look around about get all words between two strings from DB field/solr field
hell* TO *d which give me all word which are start with 'hell' and ends with 'd'
There is no way to make this by regular expresion ? search range on string? am I right ?

Comment: Where does `0113A2` get placed?

Answer (score 1):

In you question you state: "*start from '011' and end at '22'*".

The regex for that would be:

```
011.*22
```

However to match all items in your sample data:

```
011.*[012]2
```

Regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/uQ5lN2

Comment: Update answer to `011.*[012]2` since `011.*22` doesn't match `011K02`

Comment: @arun, yes thank you, I edited my answer. The OP edited his question and changed his sample data.